# Search for null objects inside array of objects using LINQ

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, linq

I am sure thats an easy one, but i cant figure it out and did not found an answer, 
I am checking if objects are null inside an array of `NumericUpDown` 
(`PrimaryWeightsValueChanged()` called by a valueChange event, before form loads they should be null).
**but the problem is that the condition is always return true even after the controls was initialized and has values** 
what am i doing wrong?

```
private NumericUpDown[] PrimaryWeightNumsAr = {
num_Primary_Billing,
num_Primary_Rutine,
num_Primary_Seker,
num_Primary_Sla
};
private void PrimaryWeightsValueChanged()
{
    // even when NumericUpDown`s are not null it enters here
    if (PrimaryWeightNumsAr.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x == null))
        return;

    // doing stuff when not null...
}
```

visual basic version:

```
Private PrimaryWeightNumsAr() As NumericUpDown = {num_Primary_Billing, num_Primary_Rutine, num_Primary_Seker, num_Primary_Sla}
Private Sub PrimaryWeightsValueChanged()
    ' even when NumericUpDown`s are not null it enters here '
    If PrimaryWeightNumsAr.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x) x Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub

    If PrimaryWeightNumsAr.AsEnumerable().Sum(Function(x) x.Value) <> 100 Then
        For Each itm As NumericUpDown In PrimaryWeightNumsAr
            itm.BackColor = GuiProfile.sys_red
        Next
    Else
        For Each itm As NumericUpDown In PrimaryWeightNumsAr
            itm.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you need exactly? If you need to check only existence of null, then you have right answer.

Comment: @YuriyN i am using also visual basic.net, i will add the vb version maybe it will be more clear

Comment: I'm sure, you don't need cast `AsEnumerable`, because array already implements it. But your code at C# absolutely the same as VB. I see that it check if any element in array is null, but all your elements in array already initialized, they can't be null.

Comment: the `Any` method always returns true even after the form was loaded (the numeric updowns are not added in run time, they are declared in the designer)

Comment: Before asking for LINQ, have you actually checked the content of your array? IMO it will always be filled with `null`s, since field initializers run before the class constructors.

Comment: Are you sure that all variables (`num_Primary_Billing` and so on) that you pass to array initializer are not null?

Comment: @AleksAndreev yes, i am sure because they all exist on the GUI..

Comment: @jonathana But they are initialized in `InitializeComponent` called from the constructor, right? See my previous comment.

Comment: You're putting a bunch of null references in an array, value null. Updating the variable isn't going to update the null references, thus always null. http://rextester.com/AKFA3202

Comment: @IvanStoev yes it is true

Comment: Then move the array initialization in the constructor (after the `InitializeComponent` call) or in `Load` event

Comment: @IvanStoev  thank you, i understand my mistake, if you like add it as an answer and it will be marked.

Comment: @jonathana Cool, glad it helped :) I'm not planning to compose answer, you could post and accept self answer if you wish. Cheers.

Comment: no problem, i will handle it for future documentation,  tnx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### (For future viewers)

According to @Ivan Stoev  comments, the problem was solved.
"since field initializers run before the class constructors".
or in other words, my array was declared before objects was initialized.

Adding the NumericUpdowns to the array after they was initialized (inside the constructor after `InitializeComponent()` was called) did the trick..
that is the summarized fixed code:

```
Public Class PerformanceForm

    Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer. '
        InitializeComponent()
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call. '
        PrimaryWeightNumsAr = {num_Primary_Billing, num_Primary_Rutine, num_Primary_Seker, num_Primary_Sla}
    End Sub
    Private PrimaryWeightNumsAr() As NumericUpDown

    Private Sub PrimaryWeightsValueChanged()

        If PrimaryWeightNumsAr Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ' do other stuff... '

    End Sub

End Class
```

**C# version:**

```
public class PerformanceForm
{

    public PerformanceForm()
    {
        // This call is required by the designer. 
        InitializeComponent();
        // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call. 
        PrimaryWeightNumsAr = {
            num_Primary_Billing,
            num_Primary_Rutine,
            num_Primary_Seker,
            num_Primary_Sla
        };
    }

    private NumericUpDown[] PrimaryWeightNumsAr;
    private void PrimaryWeightsValueChanged()
    {

        if (PrimaryWeightNumsAr == null)
            return;
        // do other stuff... 

    }

}
```